# Locked Apple ID

Tags: iphone

I just updated to IOS 9.3 and I accidentaly locked my Apple ID while logging in. I forgot the yahoo email in order to reset it. I don't know any of my security questions (because I'm an idiot and I don't write them down).

Answer (score 1):

With sufficient proof of ownership you can take your phone to the Genius Bar at an Apple Store and have them unlock it.

Make sure to [make an appointment](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar).

I think they can unlock it over the phone but it requires emailing your proof which can slow down the process.